# Superimposed images in my layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like for a tablet app some points (imageView or Button) red or green for example in an image and I want to make it similar with all kind of screen size.

This is what I want :
[image]

How can I do that ?

Comment: Your question is too general. This is forum for technical questions, not design ideas. At the very least, come up with a specific question. If you have multiple questions, post them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using `ConstraintLayout`